# python, bot, aiogram

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram, бот

Как можно реализовать такое всплывающее уведомление в телеграм боте на aiogram.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/dev-3.x/utils/callback_answer.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from aiogram import Bot, types
from aiogram.dispatcher import Dispatcher
from aiogram.utils import executor

API_TOKEN = 'your_api_token'
bot = Bot(token=API_TOKEN)
dp = Dispatcher(bot)


@dp.callback_query_handler(lambda c: c.data == 'show_notification')
async def show_notification(callback_query: types.CallbackQuery):
    # Отправляем всплывающее уведомление
    await bot.answer_callback_query(
        callback_query.id,
        text='Новое уведомление!\n<b>Здесь может быть какой-то текст</b>',
        show_alert=True,
    )


if __name__ == '__main__':
    from aiogram import executor
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

В приведенном выше коде, когда пользователь нажимает кнопку или выполняет действие, которое генерирует callback-запрос с данными 'show_notification', бот отправляет всплывающее уведомление с использованием answer_callback_query.

Обратите внимание, что параметр show_alert=True в answer_callback_query позволяет отобразить уведомление в виде всплывающего окна. Вы также можете использовать HTML-разметку в тексте уведомления для стилизации.

Этот код должен быть частью вашего общего бот-скрипта, где вы уже настроили инициализацию бота и диспетчера Aiogram.